# Cannot copy param 0 weights from layer 'conv4_3_norm_mbox_loc'

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

Is here anyone using ssd? I use ssd-caffe in windows,I meet a problem, I changed the ssd_pascal.py and ssd_pascal_video.py,but the ssd_pascal_video.py meet the following mistake:

```
 Cannot copy param 0 weights from layer 'conv4_3_norm_mbox_loc';shape mismatch.  Source param shape is 12 512 3 3 (55296); target param shape is 16 512 3 3 (73728)
```

I worked it for several hours, and I found the test.prototxt is updated automatically when running the ssd_pascal_video.py,because I'd like to change the conv4_3_norm_mbox_conf to 16,but it not work,in that case,I guess it maybe updated automatically. So the problem is how to keep consistent,I want to use 12,not 16,or how can I change the code to 12 not for 16?

Thank you for attention!

Comment: you need to use the same script to generate the `train.prototxt` and `test.prototxt`. otherwise you'll end up with such inconsistencies.

Comment: @Shai Thanks, I think this is the problem,because I download the same train.prototxt and test.prototxt,I mean they are all 12,but the ssd_pascal_video.py need the 16, how can I change it ? Is there any good methods?

Comment: you can change the python code to write to different `prototxt` files.

Comment: @Shai  Thank you! So, I have a try to change the layer's name, and the result is not ideal, there are too many bbox and they are wrong, a  troublesome question.

Comment: It is difficult to debug such problems. I have some experience with SSD. I trained it on datasets other than COCO and VOC with satisfying results.

Comment: I use it for three months,but I only have some superficial knowledge, a general understanding to it.Can you gve me a mail address if I have some questions to ask you for advice? My email address is 1073115527@qq.com

Comment: @Shai  Well, great thanks to you! I think I should look for the new py script.

Answer (score 0):

The prototxt file is generated by SSD_pascal.py file automatically